# Inheritance and abstract parmater passing

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
Abstract class A
Abstract class B extends A
class C1 extends B
class C2 extends B
class C3 extends B
```

The classes C1, C2, C3 implements the same abstract method:

```
public MyItem getItem()
```

In other class (say class X) I have (want to have...) function:

```
void testFunction(A classA)
{
   MyItem myItem = classA.getItem();
   ...
}
```

But when I'm doing that I'm getting compilation error.

I cant understand why ?  why cant I write the void testFunction(A classA) as I want ?
(I know that in c++ I can do it)

Thanks

Comment: In which class is the abstract method defined? A or B? What compilation error do you get?

Comment: Specifying the line causing the compilation error and what the error is, will help.

Comment: Without more explanation from you I cannot see anything here where C++ and Java would be so different. Didn't you rather want to say "I know that in Java Script I can do it"? :) Also your naming `testFunction` suggests that you are coming from the Java Script world :)

Comment: As a side note.. Check if you can use interfaces instead of abstract classes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that probably you did not define the method `getItem()` in the class `A`.

You can define it (without necessarily specifying a concrete implementation of it, if you don't want/can) by simply adding this line in the class `A`:

```
abstract public MyItem getItem();
```

In this way the method signature is defined in the class `A`, and you can therefore call it when you have an object declared of class `A`.

Then all *concrete* classes extending `A` (such as classes `C1`, `C2` and `C3`), must mandatory implement the method `getItem()` by overriding it. You may also add an `@Override` notation before the method implementation, for instance:

```
class C1 extends B {

   @Override
   public MyItem getItem() {
      //concrete implementation
   }
}
```